# Is there a way to get a background-image to render over moz-linear-gradients

Tags: css, firefox, background

In css you may normally set both a background-image, and a background-color, and the image will be rendered on top of the color.

```
#someDiv
{
   background-image: url(arrow.png);
   background-color: blue;
}
```

This will cause #someDiv to have a blue background with the arrow.png image above.

However, what if I want to use firefox's -moz-linear-gradient to do a gradient for the background, then is there a way to make the image render over this gradient?

EDIT:

The MDC states that gradients replace the background-image tag. So in that case, I guess a follow up question is is it possible to specify two background images and have them render one on top of another?

Comment: Have you thought about adding another div over it and setting its background with a suitable opacity value?

Comment: That could work, however, I was wondering if there's a purely css workaround. The reason being is that the div is being generated by a third party jQuery/javascript plugin (without callable API), and so I don't entirely wish to dig in and dissect its code unless I absolutely have to. (It's not that big a deal, but I was wondering if there's a simpler solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example on the Mozilla site has background gradients under background images:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/multiple_backgrounds

Comment: Insanely badass! This is why I love gecko :)

Comment: I know! I can't wait till all browsers do this =D

Comment: Awesome webkit browsers support it as well! 

(Firefox, Chrome, and Safari are the entirety of my entire targeted audience, I'm lucky I don't have to cater to IE)